# Search a doubly nested JSON structure on Mongodb

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb

I have the JSON inserted onto MongoDB. Following is the snippet of millions of records of data.

```html
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a015017c1016b72dda02b7a"),
  "88": {
    "10134": {
      "Last visit": "2016-04-04",
      "Frequency": 1,
      "Avg days": "NaT",
      "Annual Frequency": 1,
      "First visit": "2016-04-04",
      "Annual Expenditure": 100,
      "Monetory": 100,
      "Recency": 581,
      "AvgLTV": 150.76923076923075,
      "RFMClass": "344",
      "Visit_Ids": [
        140838
      ]
    }    
  }
}
```

To add more context:
88 denotes a merchant_id
10134 denotes user_id.

How would I search all the records for just the ones with a specific user_id, or a merchant_id/user_id combination ?